# Masking password input in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am building a login page using ReactJS. I am using a custom text component built in-house, but unfortunately, it does not have a password masking option. Using the `<input>` tag with `type=password` is not an option. How can I make my password field appear masked (Dots instead of text) using `Javascript/JQuery`?

Is it a viable option to read each `keydown` event and replace the text with a dot while storing the char in a list or something on those lines?

Comment: Answer might be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775342/how-to-disable-chromes-saved-password-prompt-setting-through-javascript/32775859

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, the way to achieve this is either in your JSX/HTML or by CSS for the most part.

To achieve this with JSX or HTML, you can use:

```
<input type="password" name="password">
```

To achieve this with CSS, you can use:

```
-webkit-text-security: disc;
text-security: disc;
```

Comment: `webkitTextSecurity: 'disc'` does not seem to work. Is there an alternate in React?

Comment: `WebkitTextSecurity: 'disc'` worked (with a capital W). Thanks!

Comment: Notice that -moz-text-security is deprecated and should not be used in production envs.

Answer (score 5):

I would simply condition the input type.

```
<input type={show_input?'text':'password'} 
       name='password' 
       id='password'
       value={user.password}
       onChange={handleChange}
 />
```

Change the value of show_input in your onChange function or add a button that changes shouw_input to true or false.

When type is password it will be masked, when it is text it will be unmasked.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `<input type="password">`, which does exactly that.

Comment: From my question, "Using the <input> tag with type=password is not an option."

Comment: @saishreb: Why not? That's like asking "How can I insert a screw without a screwdriver?"

Comment: The custom text component that I am using for username field has been styled in a certain way which is difficult to reproduce with CSS. The password field needs to look exactly the same as the username field.

Comment: Can we see what the username field looks like? Without it we don't really have a reference to help you. Maybe you can mask the input field.

Comment: @SLaks when we want to limit who can screw the screw... to ask a user for their password and make sure to disable `autocomplete` (which `autoComplete="off"` is not guaranteed to work in all browsers) but we also want to mask the field using browser default behavior. *Use case*: User has a **Delete Account** button but we always want to make sure the user types the password and is not auto-completed by someone else that may sit on the users computer.