# Webix How to disable autocomplete

Tags: javascript, text, autocomplete, passwords, webix

I have a textbox type password. My browser keeps me telling if I want to save my password. Is there's anyway to disable that? I already tried to add attribute for my text box I set autocomplete:off but it's still asking if I want to save my password. Is there's other way or alternative for this? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Chrome's saved password prompt setting through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775342/how-to-disable-chromes-saved-password-prompt-setting-through-javascript)

Comment: No its not. Im using webix. I think there's no autocomplete attribute for text type password