# Prevent prompt to store username / password until registration is complete?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a mobile application that helps users create an account with three screens (we do not want them to scroll) as a sort of wizard. Each screen belongs on a different route:

- `/Register`
- `/Register/2`
- `/Register/3`

I have the registration info stored in a redux store over the course of these three pages. On the first screen, `/Register`, users are prompted for a username and password. When they continue onto the second screen, the browser (Chrome) is prompting them to save their credentials for future use. Is there any way that I can prevent this until they have submitted the form on the `/Register/3` route in chrome and, preferably, in other browsers?

All routing is done on the client with `react-router` and the `history` object.

Comment: This has already been answered at length: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32836440/2052575) where a solution to change the input type to `text` and use javascript to obfuscate the characters is proposed. In the configuration you describe, may it be benificial to prompt for the credentials on the final screen?

Comment: Design team requires that credentials come first, I guess it's the most intuitive thing people will want to set. I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't require fudging with a text field, but it appears there's no alternative. Thanks.