# Hint to browser that login was incorrect

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, browser

With a login form in an SPA, where the login happens async in the background, the browser asks if I would like to save the password regardless of the login being successful.

Is there a way to hint to the browser "hey, this login wasn't correct, so maybe don't ask to save it yet"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775342/how-to-disable-chromes-saved-password-prompt-setting-through-javascript is this relevant?

Comment: Short answer: **NO**

Answer (score 1):

If you're returning an appropriate [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), the browser will usually take the hint. I.e. a successful login results in a `200 OK` status, whereas an incorrect login should result in a `400 Bad request` status code.

Comment: It comes back with status `401`

Comment: That's really an inappropriate status code, unless you're using the `Authorization` header and also return a `WWW-Authenticate` header; but that would be rather odd for a REST login endpoint.