# Prevent Browsers not to remember password

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication, form-fields

We have an application with a login screen which has input field text and password. What I am trying to achive here is;

1. Prevent browsers to **ask** if, user wants it to be memorized by
   browser.
2. Prevent all browsers **not** to **memorize** that field at any situation. Even
   if you said "yes", I want all the browsers ignore that field
   entirely.

The things I tried;

1. I tried to use `autocomplete="off"` on both form and inputs but with
   the new Firefox version, it doesn't seem to work.
2. I inserted an non-displayed input password field to trick the
   browser. But it is bad for accessibility. It also lowers the
   usability score.
3. I tried to make `autocomplete="new-password"` but internet explorer
   completely ignores it.. (like I am surprised)

So if anyone achieved a good result with any other solutions, and if it could be shared, it would be a great contribution to developer community.

[image]

Comment: You can probably make the field not look like a password field to browsers, so that message doesn't show on default browsers, but if someone really wants to save it, you can't prevent it.

Comment: What's the HTML? You could try removing attributes from the input. Could also try removing the form, but that makes it less accessible IIRC

Comment: Yes, it makes it less accessible. I want to keep on using the password input field with type attribute password. Otherwise it causes other issues :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Chrome's saved password prompt setting through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775342/how-to-disable-chromes-saved-password-prompt-setting-through-javascript)

Comment: Not really, it causes a security problem. And also less accessible as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Why is this even your goal? Are you trying to force users to type in their password every time? If so, that's a great way to get them stored in plaintext. If you do want to do this, however, you should be able to emulate a password input box by captuing keyboard event listeners.

Comment: I think you need to think about what it is you're *really* trying to achieve. And I think you might want to look at two-factor authentication (2FA). The principle there is usually that your access to the system depends on you knowing something and having something. The knowing bit is the password -- and your browser might help you know it by saving it for you. The having bit is usually implemented using a challenge-response (OTP) to a cell phone, or something like Authy if you don't want to spend $$ on SMSes. The fact that your browser might store the password then becomes less of an issue.

Comment: @DemeterDimitri Why not use `autocomplete="new-password"` for browsers that work and find an IE specific fix for this problem? I think you have discarded `autocomplete="new-password"` as if it is completely useless. Perhaps, if `autocomplete="off"` works in IE, use that for IE and use `new-password` for the rest.

Answer (score 6):

This cannot be prevented from scripts, the only way to prevent is you can disable Autofill in Browser Settings.

Answer (score 1):

You should put text input box inside a canvas.
Take a look at [CanvasInput](https://github.com/goldfire/CanvasInput) and [canvas-text-editor](https://www.everythingfrontend.com/pages/canvas-text-editor-tutorial.html).

By using canvas to draw input box you can trick browsers.

or you can use `contenteditable` on a div.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this while using an input field for passwords. I also strongly advise against you using a regular input field, because many browsers save inputs to those too (but in plain text).

Using a text box inside a canvas is not good for accessibility, and it also is completely incompatible with older browsers.

Your best bet is going to be creating a hidden `div` that you can type in via `contenteditable`, and then creating a fake password entry overlay that adds a `•` every time you type a character. This has the exact same level of treatment from the browser as a regular password input, but the browser won't prompt you to save it.

Answer (score 0):

This is Tricky

The reason is browser always watch input field type when we submit.

example

```
<input type="password">
```

when use div tag browser does not show (save popup)

example(you want to write some huge logic to hide password)

```html
<div contenteditable="true">username</div>
<div contenteditable="true">password</div>
```

otherwise you want to manually disable autofilling and popup in your browser