# How to stop autofill for input type as password in ASP.Net using chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, passwords, autofill

After loading the page saved email/ passwords are showing on a textbox input type as password.

`<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />` is not working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your browser has saved username and password for this website. so when you try to login, Chrome provide login credentials for you. And that's not autocomplete feature.

Comment: Correct but I wan't to know the trick to avoid the display of saved credentials in textbox.

Comment: @GopalBiswas in that case you should use `autocomplete="new-password"`. make sure you have updated version of Chrome

Comment: Not working for me. Thanks for the suggestion @dumb_genius

Comment: not ideal, because mobile chrome will start nagging about "generating a strong password" with a panel above keyboard

Answer (score 0):

chrome://settings/passwords

Try deleting the saved password for the site at.

and  for all clients who using this site

[How to disable Chrome's saved password prompt setting through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775342/how-to-disable-chromes-saved-password-prompt-setting-through-javascript/32775859)

Comment: It will resolve my local machine problem but not a suitable solution for clients who using this software.